# running on an incline vs running faster on a flat plane

Tags: running, exercise, treadmill

I've started working out on the tredmill at 12km/hr for 30 minutes almost every day. For the last 3 minutes I kick it up to 14-15km/hr. Is this a good workout or am I better to run on an incline but slower?

Comment: @Jay-what are your fitness goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running flat will tend to train your stamina while running on an incline will help to increase your leg endurance and strength. So the answer depends on your running goals.